# php for loop for an array that takes values from function

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a function which is returning some values. I want to put those values in an array after checking if the current value exists. I 've written the following code:

```
$return[0]=myexec_proc($varsearch,$get_input1);

if (isset($return[0])){
$return[1]=myexec_proc($varsearch,$return[0]);
}
if (isset($return[1])){
$return[2]=myexec_proc($varsearch,$return[1]);
}
if (isset($return[2])){
$return[3]=myexec_proc($varsearch,$return[2]);
}
if (isset($return[3])){
$return[4]=myexec_proc($varsearch,$return[3]);
}
```

which works as I want to but I need to do it with a for loop.
I've tried this:

```
$return=array();

for($i=0; $i=3; $i++){
if (isset($return[$i])){
$return[$i+1]=myexec_proc($varsearch,$return[$i]);
}}
```

but I get no data and after a while I get a php fatal error "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded".
Any tips on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: That's the wrong format for a for loop; you need `for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++){` - yours will loop infinitely, as you noticed.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I thought both ways were right so I hadn't checked the one you wrote. :S

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make - you'd think PHP would flag it as an error, but apparently it's valid syntax. I just hope never to come across code where that functionality is required....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second condition of your for loop is incorrect. You are assigning $i to 3 instead of checking it as a conditional.

It should be something like this:

```
    for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++){
        if (isset($return[$i])){
            $return[$i+1]=myexec_proc($varsearch,$return[$i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For loops require a condition which they loop ***up until***. Add a less than operator to make the for run correctly.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
  if (isset($return[$i])) {
    $return[$i+1]=myexec_proc($varsearch,$return[$i]);
  }
}
```